# Our down for maintenance page is unreadable

Tags: bug, design

Got hit with a brief down for maintenance page earlier in the evening and was saddened to see this:

[image: white one white text]

The white on white isn't a particularly great look for us

Comment: Can you link to that page directly or just an error happen first?

Comment: @fredsbend I'm not sure how to find that page when there's not an error :). I don't remember getting a redirect either, so it may have been the main page when down for an error.

Answer (score 2):

This is still an issue. SE, can please fix? :)